# PHP chrome-php / headless-chromium-php

Tags: php, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

Hello I am using `the chrome-php` & `headless-chromium` packages for PHP and installed the package, on the web server I get this error:

```
Exception: RuntimeException: Cannot read chrome version, make sure you provided the correct chrome executable using: "chrome". Additional info: sh: 1: exec: chrome: not found
```

I am using a Mac and have this in my `~/.zshrc file`:

```
alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
export chrome=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

and `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
```

In some of the solutions online relating to this issue its asking me to make Chrome executable which I have

Answer (score 1):

Your web server isn't going to have access to the alias that you defined in your user's home directory.

According to https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php, you probably want to set the environmental variable CHROME_PATH in your web server to point to your Chrome executable binary.